# Using a lambda inside a method and match against a List

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I have the following code that is used for producing data for a jquery graph. However it is quite repetitive and in order to keep DRY I would like to refactor by introducing a method.

```
sb.Append("{name: 'Pull Ups', data: [");
foreach(var item in data)
{
    sb.Append(prefix); prefix = ",";
    sb.Append(item.PullUps);
}
sb.Append("]}");

sb.Append("{name: 'Push Ups', data: [");
prefix = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in data)
{
    sb.Append(prefix);  prefix = ",";
    sb.Append(item.PushUps);
}
sb.Append("]}");
```

The method I need would be something like

```
void Data(ref StringBuilder sb, string title, IList<DataDto> data,  ...)
```

And I would love my code to be something like:-

```
Data(ref sb, "Pull Ups", data, d=>d.PullUps);
Data(ref sb, "Push Ups", data, d=>d.PushUps);
Data(ref sb, "Squats", data, d=>d.Squats);
```

However I am struggling to find out how to do this. I know I need to use somthing similar along the lines of

```
private static void Data<T, TProp>(ref StringBuilder sb, 
   IList<T> data, Func<T, TProp> selector)
```

and inside (pusedocode)

```
foreach(var item in data) {
  if (selector == ???)
   sb.Append(??);
}
```

My DataDto is quite simply:-

```
public class DataDto
{
    public virtual decimal PullUps { get;  set; }
    public virtual decimal PushUps { get;  set; }
    public virtual decimal Squats { get;  set; }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Have you considered that there are better methods for producting JSON formatted data than string mashing? Lookup JavascriptSerializer.

Comment: +1 @Jamiec, I didn't even notice he's building JSON until you pointed it out.

Comment: @jamiec - you are correct, thanks for this, I only just noticed this myself! However an answer to my question will help me out in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you want something like this:

```
void YourMethod<TItem, TProp>(StringBuilder sb, string name, IList<TItem> data,
                              Func<TItem, TProp> selector)
{
    var prefix = "";
    sb.Append("{name: '"+name+"', data: [");
    foreach(var item in data)
    {
        sb.Append(prefix);
        prefix = ",";
        sb.Append(selector(item).ToString());
    }
    sb.Append("]}");
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
YourMethod(sb, "Pull Ups", data, d=>d.PullUps);
YourMethod(sb, "Push Ups", data, d=>d.PushUps);
YourMethod(sb, "Squats", data, d=>d.Squats);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about just simplifying the code you have?

```
sb.Append("{name: 'Pull Ups', data: [");
sb.Append(String.Join(",", myExercises.Select(e=>e.PullUps));}
sb.Append("]}");

sb.Append("{name: 'Push Ups', data: [");
sb.Append(String.Join(",", myExercises.Select(e=>e.PushUps));}
sb.Append("]}");
```

Also, can you have fractional pull ups, push ups or squats? Is a decimal a bit overkill?

Comment: I love the simplicity of this but I also have a little business logic in some of the selections hence extracting to a method is more desirable. However a +1 as this would fit nicely in other places of my code.

Comment: Reason it is `decimal` is it is a percentage against a national average rather than the `number` of push ups an individual can do.